# add jar files to classpath to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, classpath

in this link http://mina.apache.org/mina-project/userguide/ch1-getting-started/first-steps.html  says "Put the following jars in the classpath"
what does that mean? how can I do that in eclipse? without eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it in eclipse:

- Right click on your project
- Select Build path -> Configure Build Path
- Select libraries tab
- Click on add external jar and select the jar file by browsing your file system and click on open.
- click on ok on your configure build path screen.

Without eclipse, when you are about to compile, you will need to use:

```
javac -classpath <all jar files class path seperated by ; in windows or : on linux> java source file
```

And similar option while running the class via java command.